# Find a recurrence relation which describes the number of possible differences routes which bring the man to the roof

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

> A man interesting to climb a tower with $n$ floors. Each step he can jump one floor or two floors at once. The man can stop at most one time for rest (but he does not have to). Find a recurrence relation which describes the number of possible differences routes which bring the man to the roof.

My attempt: 
If the men can not stop at most one time so $A_n=A_{n-1}+A_{n-2}$
but I don`t know how to take into account the possibility of stopping.

EDIT:
An example for the problem:
A rest is one of the steps in the route to the roof.
The following routs are not equivalent:
1-2-3,
1-2-2-3,
1-1-2-3,
1-2-3-3,
when the first number indicates the floor which the man came after one step, the second after two steps and so on..

Comment: Can he take the rest before his first step or after his last step?

Comment: @paw88789, The first step can be - rest, jump one floor or jump two floors. if he use rest later then the possible options is only jump one floor or two. if he does not use rest then he has three options until rest is used. please see my addition to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's tricky.  I think you'd need to separate families to count the number of ways to climb $k$ floors with no stop (which I'll call $N_k$) and the number of ways to climb $k$ floors with one stop (which I'll call $S_k$).  Then we'd have:
$$N_k=N_{k-1}+N_{k-2}\\S_k=S_{k-1}+S_{k-2}+N_k$$I think $S_k$ would be the number you're looking for, since getting to the top without a break would "look" like getting to the top and then taking a break at the top.  But double-check for small values of $k$ to be sure.

Comment: if I actually set up the initial conditions right, it looks like this is http://oeis.org/A001629 , though I cannot figure out why.

Comment: @DanUznanski That's described as the number =of binary sequences of length $n$ with exactly one pair of consecutive $1$'s.  I'm not sure if that's reassuring.

Comment: Don't forget 1-2-3, 1-1-2-3, 1-2-2-3, and 1-2-3-3.  I have $N_0 = S_0 = 1$ and $N_{-1}=S_{-1}=0$, which is pretty standard.

Comment: The other thing mentions a more sensible initial value, now that I look at it, $N_0=1$, $S_0=2$.  That one's http://oeis.org/A226432 which has me even more stumped as to how it's related!

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to solve it would be  to deduce first a generating function for the problem without resting:

Let $F(x,y)= \sum_{n,k\ge0 } a_{n,k} x^ny^k$, where $k$ counts the number of decisions you make, and $a_{n,k}$ therefore is the number of ways to arrive at the desired $n$-th floor with exactly $k$ decisions.

(We'll assume that you start at floor $0$)

We can then deduce the generating function via the recurrence 
$$
a_{n,k} = a_{n-1,k-1} + a_{n-2,k-1}
$$

After that,  modify $F(x,y)$ to take resting once into account: Let's take a random decision-sequence of $k$ decisions that takes you to the desired floor. Then we have $k+1$ ways to inject our single resting-decisions into this sequence.

A little more thought gives you then that we generate any sequence in which we rest, and we generate each of those sequences exactly once.

So, we get that the generating function we're looking for is 
$$\sum_{n,k\ge0 } a_{n,k} x^ny^k + \sum_{n,k\ge0 }(k+1) a_{n,k} x^ny^k = F(x,y) + \frac d{dx} yF(x,y)$$

As we don't care about how many decisions it takes, we set $y=1$ and obtain the generating function for your problem.

If you did everything right, you'll end up with this generating function:
$$
- \frac{x^2 + x - 2}{(x^2 + x - 1)^2}
$$

Which produces the sequence $(2,3,7,13,25,...)$.

To argue for the first two values:
$n=0$ has the solutions: a)Do nothing, or b) Rest once.
$n=1$ has the solutions:  a) Go one floor up, b) Go one floor up, Rest, c) Rest, go one floor up.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A226432 is the sequence here, offset somewhat.  I have even less idea why this one would be it!

Comment: For my purposes they're the same cause they have the same starting values and the same denominator in the generating function. If you really want to demistify it, you should look why both problems got the same recurrence, I'd guess